# MySQL compare two tables and update second one using transposed select results

Tags: mysql, select, insert, compare, transpose

I have constructed the following two tables :

```
+---------------+---------------+
| name_i        | value         | 
+---------------+---------------+
| name_1        | asdf          | 
| name_1        | fdsd          | 
| name_1        | fsfd          | 
| name_2        | ffff          | 
| name_3        | erfe          |
| name_3        | ewrw          | 
| name_4        | wree          | 
| name_5        | wr4e          | 
+---------------+---------------+

+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| name_id       | column1       | column2       |column3        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| name_1        | null          | null          |null           |
| name_2        | null          | null          |null           |
| name_3        | null          | null          |null           |
| name_4        | null          | null          |null           |
| name_5        | null          | null          |null           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I want to transpose the values from first table and update the second one depending on the results from comparing their `name_id` column. For those `name_id`s which have less than 3 values the rest can remain `NULL` on the second table. So in the end my table should look like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| name_id       | column1       | column2       |column3        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| name_1        | asdf          | fdsd          |fsfd           |
| name_2        | ffff          | null          |null           |
| name_3        | erfe          | ewrw          |null           |
| name_4        | wree          | null          |null           |
| name_5        | wr4e          | null          |null           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Any idea how to do this in mysql? I am really new at this but I am guessing an appropriate for loop is needed. I have constructed the second table on my own for my convenience but if there is a way for it to be constructed directly with the appropriate values it will be fine for me.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this, especially in the database layer?  Can you not just sort the first table by `name_id` and, when iterating through the resultset in your application code, determine which column the current `value` belongs in based on what has come before?

Comment: I want to join the results of two different software tools in tabular form and I was advised to use MySQL for speed purposes (each file has approximately 30000 lines). Could you tell me how would the code look like for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one query it will be

```
UPDATE table2 SET 
    column1 = (SELECT `value` FROM table1 WHERE name_i = name_id LIMIT 1), 
    column2 = (SELECT `value` FROM table1 WHERE name_i = name_id LIMIT 1,1),
    column3 = (SELECT `value` FROM table1 WHERE name_i = name_id LIMIT 2,1)
```

Please, note what it is only for 3-column structure. Add more if you need.
It is relatively slow, but as far as you work with 30000 records - not too much

**UPD** This one will be faster

```
UPDATE table2 
    LEFT JOIN table1 a ON a.name_i = name_id 
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.name_i=b.name_i AND a.value != b.value 
    LEFT JOIN table1 c ON a.name_i=c.name_i AND a.value != c.value AND b.value != c.value 
SET 
    column1 = a.value,
    column2 = b.value,
    column3 = c.value
```

Comment: I have tried it for only one column but it takes too long. Is there another faster way?

Comment: Thank you for your answer i am trying as we speak on a server (in my local pc it took up too much memory and stopped). I was thinking more of a for loop or something as this code will be generated automatically as part of a python script but couldn't figure out how to handle that. Any ideas?

Comment: In script/loop it will be slower. Too many queries to run, to many interactions between script and DB.
How large is your DB? You said 30000, and this query will not overburden any average pc on this number of records. Do your tables have indexes? I'd like to see tables structure

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was without internet these days. The first table has 30283 rows and the second one 8122 rows. None of the tables have indexes but i can remake them in order to do so. I am planning to use this script in order to add the appropriate number of columns ( i already know how to do this) depending on the repeats of the 1st table and then i want to fill this new columns with the data. The tests i am running are currently with the 3 column setup as in my example though.

Comment: Quite the small numbers. Indexes will improve the performance. Create them for name_i, value and name_id.